# Is it impossible to mock Linq extension methods using Visual Studio 2019 Community?

Tags: c#, linq, unit-testing, moq, extension-methods

Im trying to unit test some .NET 5 code like the following with XUnit and Moq:

```
try
{
    if (this.weatherDbContext.Observations.Any())
    {
        return (DateTime)this.weatherDbContext.Observations.OrderByDescending(observation => observation.ObservationTime).FirstOrDefault().ObservationTime;
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }

}
catch (Exception)
{
    do some error handling...
}
```

I want to be able to mock a database access failure, a timeout say, so that the error handling code gets tested. (Note that Entity Framework Core 5 is being used here and I'm choosing not to have EF in a repository. This is much debated and that's the way I've gone.)

I'm aware that I can't mock the Linq methods `.Any()`, `.OrderedByDescending()`, etc as they are extension methods. I've found workarounds for this on StackExchange but they are only for extension methods that you code yourself, not Microsoft produced ones. I've tried a number of NuGet "helper" packages but they all fall foul of the extension methods issue. I'm aware of Microsoft Fakes but this seems to be available only in the paid-for versions of Visual Studio.

So am I correct to assume that it is impossible to test the failure of Linq extension methods using Visual Studio Community?

Comment: Well since this is all code you have no control over then your assumption would be accurate for this particular scenario. Short of searching MS's source code to find an execution path that can satisfy your test case.

Comment: While there is much debate about the whole repository thing. EF in your code is a 3rd party dependency you have no control over and should be treated as such.

Comment: are you aware of inmemory db for efcore5 for unit tests ? 
https://entityframeworkcore.com/providers-inmemory
When your dataset has no ObservationTime this should provoke an exception.

Comment: @Nkosi Agreed I have no control over that code. What I'm trying to test is the consequences of that code throwing an exception.

Comment: You could look into the in-memory provider approach suggested by @jeb above

Comment: @Nkosi I'm already using UseInMemoryDatabase for most of the testing here. For this specific example though, the logic will proceed without exception whether or not there are any observations. I need therefore to mock an exception such as might happen if the database disconnected.  More generally I'm trying to establish if Linq methods are inherently unmockable without Fakes.